# JSP - How to select a radio button based on an enum

Tags: jsp, enums, radio-button

My viewmodel has an enum with three possible values:

```
public enum PollFrequency {
    SixHours, TwentyFourHours, Weekly
}

public class AlertViewModel {
    private PollFrequency pollFrequency;
    public PollFrequency getPollFrequency(){
        return pollFrequency;
    }
    public void setPollFrequency(PollFrequency pollFrequency){
        this.pollFrequency = pollFrequency;
    }

    public AlertViewModel(){
        pollFrequency = PollFrequency.TwentyFourHours;
    }
}
```

My JSP page has a set of three radio buttons:

```
<input checked="<c:if test="${viewModel.pollFrequency eq 'SixHours'}">checked</c:if>" type="radio" name="checkEvery" value="checkEvery6Hours" /> 6 Hours<br />
<input checked="<c:if test="${viewModel.pollFrequency eq 'TwentyFourHours'}">checked</c:if>" type="radio" name="checkEvery" value="checkEvery24Hours" /> 24 Hours<br />
<input checked="<c:if test="${viewModel.pollFrequency eq 'Weekly'}">checked</c:if>" type="radio" name="checkEvery" value="checkEveryWeek" /> Weekly
```

I'd like to set the checked property of the radio buttons based on the enum value, but currently the last radio button is always checked. I found some threads on how to do it with springsource, but I'm not using that. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<input type="radio" <c:if test="${model.thing eq 'Thing1'}">checked</c:if> name="thing" value="thing1" /> Thing1<br />
<input type="radio" <c:if test="${model.thing eq 'Thing2'}">checked</c:if> name="thing" value="thing2" /> Thing2<br />
<input type="radio" <c:if test="${model.thing eq 'Thing3'}">checked</c:if> name="thing" value="thing3" /> Thing3
```

Comment: I understand how this is supposed to work, but I keep getting the last radio button selected. One sec as I format code for post..

Comment: Ok, I couldn't figure out to put code in a comment so I edited the original post to reflect your changes in my objects. When I run this, the last radio button is always selected. Any ideas?

Comment: May be value of `pollFrequency` is set to `Weekly`. Please remove `checked=`. You can rewrite as `<c:if test="${model.thing eq 'Thing1'}">checked='checked'</c:if>`